# Vim NERDTree re-size vsplit

Tags: linux, command-line, vim

I am using the NERDTree plugin for Vim. When using the `s: open vsplit command`, is it possible to resize the windows so that the file takes up a larger portion of the screen than the directory tree?

Comment: Weird, so you are saying the directory tree has the same width as the document? How many documents do you have opened? If just one then you should use `Enter`, not `s`.

Answer (score 11):

For **vertical** resizing use the following command:

```
CTRL-W -        Decrease current window height by N (default 1).
CTRL-W +        Increase current window height by N (default 1).
```

**Explanation:**

- In command mode, press a number `N` then press `CTRL+W` then press `-` or `+` to resize the window by `N` rows.
- Or just press `CTRL+W` and then press `-` or `+` to resize the window by 1 row.

Or, you can type `:res +/-N`. Like: `:res +10`

---

For **Horizontal** resizing use the following command:

```
CTRL-W < Decrease current window width by N (default 1).
CTRL-W > Increase current window width by N (default 1).
```

**Explanation:**

- In command mode, press a number `N` then press `CTRL+W` then press `<` or `>` to resize the window by `N` columns.
- Or just press `CTRL+W` and then press `<` or `>` to resize the window by 1 column.

Or, you can type `:vertical res +/-N`. Like: `:vertical res +10`

Comment: Great example and explanation. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 7):

You can set the default width of NERDTree through `NERDTreeWinSize`.

For example: 
`let NERDTreeWinSize = 1` in `.vimrc`.

You can adjust the size of the windows through the normal VIM commands, see `:help window-resize`.

Answer (score 4):

Check your settings for **equalalways** and **eadirection**, as they dictate what size new windows start out as.  If *equalalways* is set, then all new windows will be created equal in width, height, or both, depending on the value of *eadirection*.

Also, the NERDTree setting: **NERDTreeWinSize** defaults to a width of 31 characters, you may want to adjust that (after checking the *equalalways* and *eadirection* options in vim too)

Comment: I had the problem where my `NERDTree` window kept changing width when closing other windows and this pointed me to `noequalalways` which fixed that